# Pandas Error: '[nan nan] not found in axis' while dropping a column without labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop the first two columns in a dataframe that has NaN for column headers. The dataframe looks like this:

```
**15 NaN NaN          NaN           Energy Supply  Energy Supply Renewable Energy**
  17 NaN Afghanistan  Afghanistan   1              2             3
  18 NaN Albania      Albania       1              2             3
  19 NaN Algeria      Algeria       1              2             3
```

I need to drop the first two columns labeled NaN. I tried `df=df.drop(df.columns[[1,2]],axis=1)`, which returns an error
What am I missing?

> KeyError: '[nan nan] not found in axis'

Comment: Try `df[df.columns.dropna()]`?

Answer (score 0):

Strange you have `NaN` as columns. Please try filter columns that do not start with `NaN` using `regex`.

```
df.filter(regex='^(?!NaN).+', axis=1)
```

**Using your data**

```
print(df)
  15  NaN        NaN.1        NaN.2  EnergySupply  EnergySupply.1  \
0  17  NaN  Afghanistan  Afghanistan             1               2   
1  18  NaN      Albania      Albania             1               2   
2  19  NaN      Algeria      Algeria             1               2   

   RenewableEnergy  
0                3  
1                3  
2                3
```

**Solution**

```
print(df.filter(regex='^(?!NaN).+', axis=1))
       15   EnergySupply   EnergySupply.1    RenewableEnergy
    0  17             1               2                3
    1  18             1               2                3
    2  19             1               2                3
```

Comment: This didn't throw an error anymore, but returns the same df with NaN columns. Here's what I used,
df=df.filter(regex='^(?!NaN).+', axis=1)
df.head()

Comment: Should work. Make it `df=df.filter(regex='^(?!NaN).+', axis=1)`

Comment: No, still the same (no error, but returns original dataframe). Does it make a difference that I am using an excel?

Comment: What version of pandas are you on?

Comment: python           : 3.8.3.final.0
pandas           : 1.0.5

Comment: Either a problem with your csv file or the package versions.

Comment: Try using df=df.filter(regex='^(?!nan).+', axis=1)

Comment: For 3.7 had to put nan instead of NaN. `df=df.filter(regex='^(?!nan).+', axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

When the NaN columns exist, I had to do a case-insenstive version of the regex from [wwnde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63664615/881411) in order for them to successfully filter out the column:

```
df = df.filter(regex='(?i)^(?!NaN).+', axis=1)
```

Other suggestions, such as `df=df[df.columns.dropna()]` and `df=df.drop(np.nan, axis=1)` do not work, but the above did.

I'm guessing this is related to the painful reality of `np.nan == np.nan` not evaluating to true, but ultimately it seems like a bug with pandas.